# Using ast to create a function with a keyword-only argument that has a default value

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, keyword-argument

I'm trying to use `ast` to dynamically create a function with a keyword-only argument that has a default value. However, the resulting function still requires the argument and will raise `TypeError` if it's not passed.

This is the code creating the function `f`:

```py
import ast
import types

module_ast = ast.Module(
    body=[
        ast.FunctionDef(
            name='f',
            args=ast.arguments(
                args=[],
                vararg=None,
                kwarg=None,
                defaults=[],
                kwonlyargs=[
                    ast.arg(
                        arg='x',
                        lineno=1,
                        col_offset=0,
                    ),
                ],
                kw_defaults=[
                    ast.Num(n=42, lineno=1, col_offset=0),
                ],
                posonlyargs=[],
            ),
            body=[ast.Return(
                value=ast.Name(id='x', ctx=ast.Load(), lineno=1, col_offset=0),
                lineno=1,
                col_offset=0,
            )],
            decorator_list=[],
            lineno=1,
            col_offset=0,
        )
    ],
    type_ignores=[],
)

module_code = compile(module_ast, '<ast>', 'exec')

# This is the part that I'm suspicious of
f_code = next(c for c in module_code.co_consts if isinstance(c, types.CodeType))

f = types.FunctionType(
    f_code,
    {}
)
```

If I `print(ast.unparse(module_ast))`, I get what I expect:

```py
def f(*, x=42):
    return x
```

Calling `f(x=100)` returns `100` as expected, but calling `f()` produces:

```
TypeError: f() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'x'
```

I suspect that the problem is in way the I'm turning the AST into a function. I saw the approach in another question here (which I unfortunately do not have a link to). It looks a bit dodgy, but I'm not sure how else to do it.

Comment: If you look at the disassembly of ``module_code``, you can see that it includes the code to a) *build* a function object with x=42, and b) the function *body* ``return x``. It seems you must actually execute the module code to build the function, the same way ``def f...`` needs executing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function's default argument values aren't part of the function's code object. They can't be, because the defaults are created at function definition time, not bytecode compilation time. Default argument values are stored in `__defaults__` for non-keyword-only arguments and `__kwdefaults__` for keyword-only arguments. When you extract `f_code` from `module_code`, you're not getting any information about defaults.

*Execute* the function definition, then retrieve the actual function object:

```
namespace = {}
exec(module_code, namespace)
function = namespace['f']
```